# ClassNotFoundException when using Jetpack Compose inside a library

Tags: gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on a Photo Editor library as a playground project to learn `Jetpack Compose`.

The library exposes an `Activity` that the client should launch and the editor library should do its magic. This is why I'm expecting the library to be used by apps that does not yet use `Compose`.

Having said all of the above, when I include my library `AAR` to a sample app, I'm getting a lot of class not found exceptions.

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.compose.material.ColorsKt"`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaKt"`

**Important to mention that the library is not minified (no obfuscation)**

Here is the list of dependencies I'm using in the library:

```
ext {
    compose_version = '1.1.1'
    kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    ktx_version = '2.4.1'
}

dependencies {
    // general dependencies
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$ktx_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$ktx_version"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'

    // kotlin dependencies
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1'

    // compose dependencies
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"

    // navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.2'

    // gpu image
    implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android:gpuimage:2.1.0'

    // test dependencies
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I added compose dependencies that were used by library to the host application as well. E.g. `implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.1.1'`, `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.1'`

To be clean I added dependencies to .pom shipped with AAR so library user does not need to worry about adding those manually.

As an added bonus I also tried to start my library compose UI in Java host application and it works. Great for flexibility.

Hope this helps you